# systemctl start openvpn@vpn.example.com launches openvpn in 2 processes

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

Why running `systemctl start openvpn@vpn.example.com`  starts openvpn with 2 different processeS?

```
nobody    3971  0.0  0.0  54756  6828 ?        Ss   14:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-vpn.example.com --status /run/openvpn/vpn.example.com.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/vpn.example.com.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/vpn.example.com.pid
root      3972  0.0  0.0  57220  5168 ?        S    14:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-vpn.example.com --status /run/openvpn/vpn.example.com.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/vpn.example.com.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/vpn.example.com.pid
```

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04.